# Why are inductors not used in impulse generators?

Tags: inductor

There are many impulse generators like Marx, which are based on capacitors, but very few on inductors. It seems to me that the same can be achieved by removing the constant flow of current through the inductor, resulting in huge voltage.

Why are inductors not "standard" in generating impulse voltages?

Comment: What are you talking about? For example, every gasoline engine and every CRT-based TV set use inductors in exactly that way to generate high voltages. The same technique is used at lower voltages in boost-mode SMPSs.

Comment: Ever seen an ignition coil?

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that inductors tend to be a bit less ideal, meaning they may have  parallel resistance/capacitance and series resistance that prevent the ideal IV characteristic.

The current would also have to stop very abruptly (high dI/dT). Where with the Marx generator the voltage source can be DC, the spark gaps cause the fast action.

If you are curious for more impulse generators, using a diode's recovery time can generate nanosecond-picosecond pulses, even for a relatively slow rising/falling edge.